# Error in full_join in dplyr with a POSIXct object

Tags: r, datetime, merge, dplyr, time-series

I have two data frames I am trying to merge (called `d1` and `small`). I exported each data frame and made them available [here](https://figshare.com/s/ace5b44bc12394a7c46d).

The `d1` dataframe was used to generate the `small` data frame. I used a series of `for if` loops to determine the presence/absence (in two hour bins) of each species (`sps`) in the `d1` dataset to generate the `small` dataset.

What I am trying to do is take the `TRUE`/`FALSE` rows from `small` and merge them with `d1` to get something like this (hypothetical example):

```
         datetime     MUVI80 MUXX80 MICRO80 TAHU80 TAST80 ERDO80 LEAM80 ONZI80 MEME80 MAMO80 sps  pp      datetime        km crossingtype
1 2012-06-19 01:42:00  FALSE  FALSE    TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE FALSE  FALSE  FALSE MICRO  0  2012-06-19 02:19    80  Exploration
2 2012-06-21 21:42:00  FALSE   TRUE   FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE FALSE  FALSE  FALSE MUXX   1  2012-06-21 23:23    80      Unknown
3 2012-07-15 09:42:00  FALSE  FALSE   FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE FALSE  FALSE   TRUE MAMO   0  2012-07-15 11:38    80     Complete
4 2012-07-20 21:42:00  FALSE  FALSE    TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE FALSE  FALSE  FALSE MICRO  0  2012-07-20 22:19    80  Exploration
5 2012-07-29 21:42:00  FALSE  FALSE    TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE FALSE  FALSE  FALSE MICRO  0  2012-07-29 23:03    80  Exploration
6 2012-08-08 23:42:00  FALSE  FALSE    TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE FALSE  FALSE  FALSE MICRO  0  2012-08-07 02:04    80     Complete
```

While both datasets share a common field `datetime`, they are formatted differently and this is causing problems for two reasons:

1. The `datetime` field is a `POSIXct` object in `small` but not in `d1`.
2. To create the `datetime` field in `small` I also made time bins of 2 hours (i.e. I asked, in a two hour period was the species present (`TRUE`) or absent (`FALSE`)). This means the `datetime` field will not have exact matches between the `small` and `d1` datasets. Rather, the `datetime` field in `d1` is anywhere within 2 hours of the `datetime` field in `small`.

Therefore, when I try:

```
time<-dplyr::full_join(small, d1, by = "datetime")
```

It obviously does not work.

The error I get is as follows:

```
Error in full_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y, suffix$x, suffix$y, check_na_matches(na_matches)) : cannot join a POSIXct object with an object that is not a POSIXct object
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can:

1. Check what formats the different `datetime` fields are in and then coerce them to the same format.
2. Merge these two data sets (despite the hour mismatch in the `datetime` fields).

Comment: Can you share both the data sets?

Comment: Note that a better way to coerce the `datetime` field to the same format is simply: `datetime=ymd_hm(datetime)` from the `lubridate` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package `sqldf` provides flexibility to handle scenarios with `range` based joining of data.frame and tables. Let me demonstrate the way `sqldf` can be used to resolve issue mentioned in OP.

```
I started with reading data from files shared in OP. 

library(sqldf)

# Read the data from d1.txt. Pretty straight forward.
d1 <- read.table("d1.txt", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# The datetime column is character. Hence change it to POSIXct
d1$datetime <- as.POSIXct(d1$datetime)

# small.txt file doesn't contain datetime together. Need to introduce 
# another column as onlytime to read time part separately. 
small <- read.table("small.txt", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# merge onlytime part with date part in datetime column
small$datetime = paste(small$datetime, small$onlytime, sep = " ")
# drop column onlytime
small$onlytime <- NULL
# Now datetime column is character. Hence change it to POSIXct
small$datetime <- as.POSIXct(small$datetime)

# everything is ready now. Lets join two dataframes
# small$datetime is at 2 hours interval and represent data for past 2 hours
# Hence range matching records to be found within 2 hours(2*60*60) before and 
# time of current row

time = sqldf("select * from d1
                inner join small
               on d1.datetime between (small.datetime - 2*60*60) and small.datetime")


head(time, 3)
     ID       date   sps  time pp            datetime km crossingtype            datetime MUVI80 MUXX80 MICRO80 TAHU80 TAST80 ERDO80 LEAM80 ONZI80
1 15185 2012-10-22 MICRO  3:42  0 2012-10-22 03:42:00 80      Unknown 2012-10-22 03:42:00  FALSE  FALSE    TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
2 15187 2012-10-23 MICRO  0:40  0 2012-10-23 00:40:00 80      Unknown 2012-10-23 01:42:00  FALSE  FALSE    TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
3 17018 2012-10-29 MICRO 21:03  0 2012-10-29 21:03:00 80      Unknown 2012-10-29 21:42:00  FALSE  FALSE    TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
```

Join type can be changed to fit actual object in OP.

Comment: This is perfect. It does exactly what I need. Thank you for the clear answer!